# Cannot convert type 'any' to IVehicle

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am getting a strange issue after updating my Typescript version to 2.x.

```
this.selectedVehicle = null;
```

This used to work, but now I get an error

> Cannot convert type 'any' to IVehicle

Everything compiles but VS2017 puts a red line under it.

Is this a VS issue or have I missed some new strict Typescript setting? Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./src/app/bootstrap.ts"
    ]
}
```